# how to choose secure PPTP password?

Tags: vpn, password, pptp

I'm running a PPTP server on a ubuntu VPS, which has around 20 users . currently we use passwords like this "bi9_Knh78A#" . is this considered safe ? What's the best method to choose passwords ?
How secure is PPTP VPN when passwords are very strong ? any tip to increase security ?

Comment: If you are really worried about security, are you sure that PPTP is the correct choice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: I've never seen it better explained then here...]

That sums it up.

Comment: Dammit, you beat me to it!